# Why is the Gamma function defined by the definite integral for $\Re(z) >0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, gamma-function

[Gamma Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html) gives the integral definition of the gamma function as

\begin{equation*} \tag{1}
    \Gamma(z) := \int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1}\,\,dt, \text{ for } \Re(z) > 0.
\end{equation*}

Why is $(1)$ defined for $\Re(z) > 0$? Could I not have $\Gamma(3i) = \int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}t^{-1+3i}\,\,dt$ for example? 
Can I write 'The integral definition of the gamma function is:
\begin{equation*} 
    \Gamma(z) := \int_{0}^\infty e^{-t}t^{z-1}\,\,dt, \text{ for } \Re(z) \geq 0 \text{ and } z\neq 0?'
\end{equation*}

Comment: Perhaps the $t^{-1}$ term in $\int\limits_{0}^\infty e^{-t}t^{3i}t^{-1}\,\,dt$ causes problems

Comment: @Henry Okay cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int_1^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{z-1}\, dt$ exists for all complex numbers $z$ but $\int_0^{1} e^{-t} |t^{z-1}|\, dt=\int_0^{1} e^{-t} t^{x-1}\, dt$ where $x$ is the real part of $z$ and this integral is finite iff $x>0$.

In particular $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} t^{i-1}\, dt$ does not exist so you cannot use this integral to define $\Gamma (i)$.

Comment: Okay. So is the functional equation $$\zeta(s) = 2^s\pi^{s-1}\sin \Bigl(\frac{s\pi}{2}\Bigr)\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s), \text{ for } \Re(s) \leq 1 \text{ and } s \neq 0,1$$ valid at $s=1+3i$?

Comment: When I use Wolfram alpha to evaluate the integral, https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E(-t)t%5E(-1%2Bi)+dt+from+0+to+infinity , it evaluates $\Gamma(i)$, i think. Is there an alternative definition to evaluate $\Gamma(z)$?

Comment: Before deriving the functional equation for $\zeta$ function one shows that there is a unique  analytic function on $\mathbb C \setminus \{0,-1,-2,\cdots\}$ which coincides with the Gamma function defined by you for $\Re z >0$. The extended functions is also denoted by $\Gamma$.